# Save image in the internal memory to the url

Tags: android, image

I am using this code to save the image I'm not sure if it's right

```
public String baixarImagem(String urlC, String nomeImagem) throws MalformedURLException {
    URL url = new URL(urlC);

    InputStream input = null;
    FileOutputStream output = null;

    try {
        String outputName = nomeImagem + ".jpg";

        input = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
        output = context.openFileOutput(outputName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        int read;
        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
        while ((read = input.read(data)) != -1)
            output.write(data, 0, read);

        return outputName;

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (output != null)
                output.close();

            if (input != null)
                input.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

someone can tell me if he's right. I am looking to recover is saved image and show in a listview I have no idea how to do this if anyone knows tell me

Comment: Have you actually tried the code? Did it work the way you want? We can't really help if you don't provide us with an issue that you are having with that code.

Comment: to using this code to save , I need to know how to retrieve the saved image for this codeto using this code to save , I need to know how to retrieve the saved image for this code